# Error in mutate_impl(.data, dots) : Evaluation error: Only year, quarter, month, week, and day periods are allowed for an index of class Date

Tags: r, dplyr, time-series, tidyverse, anomaly-detection

I am using `Anomalize` package to detect the Anomalies, but I am getting the mentioned error even though I have defined the `Date` as index :

Sample Code :

```
x <- as.data.frame(data %>%
  group_by(date,acc_id) %>%
  summarise(count = as.numeric(n_distinct(d_id))) %>%
  ungroup())

x$acc_id <- as.character(x$acc_id)

x <- x %>% 
  tibbletime::as_tbl_time(index = date)


x %>%
  time_decompose(count, method = "twitter", trend = "2 months") %>%
  anomalize(remainder, method = "gesd") %>%
  time_recompose() %>%
  plot_anomalies(time_recomposed = TRUE)
```

Error :

> Error in mutate_impl(.data, dots) :    Evaluation error: Only year,
>   quarter, month, week, and day periods are allowed for an index of
>   class Date.

```
dput(head(x))

structure(list(date = structure(c(17532, 17532, 17532,  17532, 17532, 17532), class = "Date"), acc_id = c("a44444",  "gg555", "0195459b-5809-4b54-89b5-1a4376c9f126",  "ggg6546", "hhjh77",  "hhjh68777"), count = c(3, 1, 1, 1,  1, 1)), .Names = c("date", "acc_id", "count"), row.names = c(NA, 
-6L), class = c("tbl_time", "tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), index_quo = ~date, index_time_zone = "UTC")
```

I have the objective to group by date and some other factor not alone with the date.

Answer (score 5):

I had the same issue. What helped me was to correctly define your date format:

```
library(tibbletime)
x <- as_tbl_time(x, index = date)

x %>% 
  as_period("daily")
```

Answer (score 1):

From the help:

> **frequency**  Controls the seasonal adjustment (removal of seasonality).
>   Input can be either "auto", a time-based definition (e.g. "2 weeks"),
>   or a numeric number of observations per frequency (e.g. 10). Refer to
>   time_frequency().
>
> **trend**   Controls the trend component For stl, the
>   trend controls the sensitivity of the lowess smoother, which is used
>   to remove the remainder. For twitter, the trend controls the period
>   width of the median, which are used to remove the trend and center the
>   remainder.

I think you swapped them:

```
x %>%
  time_decompose(count, method = "twitter", frequency* = "2 months") %>%
  anomalize(remainder, method = "gesd") %>%
  time_recompose() %>%
  plot_anomalies(time_recomposed = TRUE)
```

But it's hard to tell if there are any other problems, as the data is not enough

Answer (score 1):

There is missing a "group_by" at this pipeline. This error is also in the examples of the anomalize package.  Error was gone after adding it. This worked:

```
x %>%
  group_by(acc_id) %>%
  time_decompose(count, method = "twitter", trend = "2 months") %>%
  anomalize(remainder, method = "gesd") %>%
  time_recompose() %>%
  plot_anomalies(time_recomposed = TRUE)
```

Answer (score 0):

I was getting this error as well, until I removed duplicate dates. I was trying to run the code on data that had multiple observations for each site. Once I aggrigated to single obs per day, all was well.